# react-hot-loader v4, where should be hot?

Tags: redux, react-hot-loader

I have a two components, App and Root.
App has routes, and presents common layouts.

```
const App = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Routes />
  </Layout>
)

const Root = () => (
  <Providers>
    <App />
  </Providers>
)
```

while `Providers` contains redux's `Provider`, redux-persist's `PersistGate`, and react-router-redux's `ConnectedRouter`.

so, my main question is

1. Where should i put `hot(module)(Component)` helper? on `App`? or on `Root`?

And these are about `AppContainer` API.

2. What's the difference between `hot` helper and `AppContainer`? Is there any special cases that `AppContainer` is more proper than `hot`?

Comment: Did you ever find out an answer Fourwings?

Comment: well, no. But 1. I applied hot loader on Root side, cause It doesn't seems to have any differences in runtime, I just picked upper-level component. 2. Still don't know. waiting for answer...

Answer (score 0):

**AppContainer vs hot**

> Prior v4 the right way to setup React Hot Loader was to wrap your
>   `Application` with `AppContainer`, set setup module acceptance by
>   yourself. This approach is still valid but only for advanced use
>   cases, prefer using hot helper.

**React Hot Loader v4:**

```
// App.js
import React from 'react'
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader'

const App = () => <div>Hello world!</div>

export default hot(module)(App)
```

---

```
// main.js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './containers/App'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

*Where should i put hot(module)(Component) helper? on App? or on Root?*

You should make your App hot, Because u will be editing your root component rarely, 
But the contents inside app will be updated often.